# Problem with lstlistings inside tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, lstlisting

i have defined my new command:

```
% sets for lstlisting
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
frame=single,
rulecolor=\color{colorCodeBorder}
}

\newcommand{\mynote}[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=black!50]
{#1}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
```

and try to use it with lstlisting

```
\mynote{
always use this command:
\begin{lstlisting}
some code
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

but get error:

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line ...
```

**How could it be resolved?**

EDIT: if i skip my command then it is ok:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=black!20]
Always use this code:
\begin{lstlisting}
some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

but i need to call it by \mynote due to other issues...
**So am i doing sth wrong with defining my command?**
Be gratefull for your any help..

Answer (score 1):

You can't conveniently put `\verb`-like code (such as a listing) inside a macro argument. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494796/73317) for an explanation. But you can use an environment instead, and the `\newtcblisting` command from `tcolorbox` helps a lot to define one:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}    % or 'listings' if you use XeTeX

\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
}

\newtcblisting{mynotesidebyside}[1]{listing only, colframe=black!50,
  comment side listing, comment={#1}}

\newtcblisting{mynoteinside}[1]{listing only, colframe=black!50,
  comment and listing, comment={#1}}

\newtcblisting{mynoteabove}[1]{listing only, colframe=black!50,
  comment above listing, comment={#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mynotesidebyside}{Always use this code:}
 a = (b < c) ? d : e;
 f = &a;
\end{mynotesidebyside}

\begin{mynoteinside}{Always use this code:}
 a = (b < c) ? d : e;
 f = &a;
\end{mynoteinside}

\begin{mynoteabove}{Always use this code:}
 a = (b < c) ? d : e;
 f = &a;
\end{mynoteabove}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, but what i want to have such a panel together with normal text and some code?
.. i'll edit my question.. it is not possible?

Comment: Your question didn't include normal text, it didn't even have a minimal working example! Please see the updated answer.